# How can I use a web service in my wordpress website?

Tags: php, android, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress. I have a wordpress site that show some posts. I want to get 3 last posts of an android application and show it automatically in my site.
I get an API web service from application admin but i don't know how can I use these codes in my wordpress site. please help me!

this is a web service for getting the last 20 posts of application.

```
url: http://data.example.com/mobiles/feeds
method: post

body: 
{
"date":""
}
```

and this is a web service for getting complete content of a post:

```
url: http://data.example.com/mobiles/getFullDescription
method: post

body: 
{
"title_id":"110"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use WP Simple Web Services plugin. or follow urls below that can be

[Is there a WordPress plugin to create a web services (API) for a WordPress blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924052/is-there-a-wordpress-plugin-to-create-a-web-services-api-for-a-wordpress-blog)

http://scotty-t.com/2012/02/09/wordpress-web-services/